# 400Error for github page during deployment

Tags: github, deployment, github-pages

deployError: Request failed with status code 400
deployEnvironment URL '' is not a valid http(s) URL, so it will not be shown as a link in the workflow graph.

`` Annotations 2 errors and 1 warning [deploy](https://github.com/g1jung/g1jung.github.io/runs/5582085261?check_suite_focus=true) Error: Request failed with status code 400 [deploy](https://github.com/g1jung/g1jung.github.io/runs/5582085261?check_suite_focus=true) Error: Request failed with status code 400 [deploy](https://github.com/g1jung/g1jung.github.io/runs/5582085261?check_suite_focus=true) Environment URL '' is not a valid http(s) URL, so it will not be shown as a link in the workflow graph.` Run actions/deploy-pages@v1 Actor: github-pages[bot] Action ID: 199[7](https://github.com/g1jung/g1jung.github.io/runs/5582085261?check_suite_focus=true#step:3:7)1[8](https://github.com/g1jung/g1jung.github.io/runs/5582085261?check_suite_focus=true#step:3:8)1237 Artifact URL: https://pipelines.actions.githubusercontent.com/cOVa[9](https://github.com/g1jung/g1jung.github.io/runs/5582085261?check_suite_focus=true#step:3:9)8njkxPlL99vZUZ2Ix4ySCmpPJRbMo7hQhVZgA7RC0CaUM/_apis/pipelines/workflows/1997181237/artifacts?api-version=6.0-preview {"count":1,"value":[{"containerId":3574166,"size":4904960,"signedContent":null,"fileContainerResourceUrl":"https://pipelines.actions.githubusercontent.com/cOVa98njkxPlL99vZUZ2Ix4ySCmpPJRbMo7hQhVZgA7RC0CaUM/_apis/resources/Containers/3574166","type":"actions_storage","name":"github-pages","url":"https://pipelines.actions.githubusercontent.com/cOVa98njkxPlL99vZUZ2Ix4ySCmpPJRbMo7hQhVZgA7RC0CaUM/_apis/pipelines/1/runs/119/artifacts?artifactName=github-pages","expiresOn":"2022-06-15T07:19:42.1992681Z","items":null}]} Creating deployment with payload: { "artifact_url": "https://pipelines.actions.githubusercontent.com/cOVa98njkxPlL99vZUZ2Ix4ySCmpPJRbMo7hQhVZgA7RC0CaUM/_apis/pipelines/1/runs/[11](https://github.com/g1jung/g1jung.github.io/runs/5582085261?check_suite_focus=true#step:3:11)9/artifacts?artifactName=github-pages&%24expand=SignedContent", "pages_build_version": "f40cef829c3c64341ed7806a74a1aff265496c80", "oidc_token": "***" } Failed to create deployment for f40cef829c3c64341ed7806a74a1aff265496c80. {"message":"Deployment request failed for f40cef829c3c64341ed7806a74a1aff265496c80 due to in progress deployment. Please cancel e5b26fbdb89226b7cc141d5d411ba5aa0a6ee2bc first or wait for it to complete.","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-github-pages-deployment"} Error: Error: Request failed with status code 400 Error: Error: Request failed with status code 400 Sending telemetry for run id 199718[12](https://github.com/g1jung/g1jung.github.io/runs/5582085261?check_suite_focus=true#step:3:12)37 ``

So the problem is obvious. I never tried to modify other files except for social-media.yml. At first, at email part, it said url : "mailto:" but I misunderstood how to change that part and I fixed it with my email. However, I realized that is for url so I tried to fix with every way include "mailto:" but now every deployment cause an error 400. What should I do?

and this is my github project link: https://github.com/g1jung/g1jung.github.io

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Is it a general problem?

Comment: I guess so. Everything worked fine until a couple of hours ago.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github pages fails to deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71511767/github-pages-fails-to-deploy)

Comment: Everything working again, see [GitHub Status](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/dcnvr6zym66r?utm_ts=1647589024).

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced the same issue, the github pages api thinks that there is a deployment in progress but in fact there isn't.

https://github.community/t/pages-deploy-wedged-incorrect-request-failed-due-to-in-progress-deployment/234793/3

see this link and try the method, you will need an ubuntu vm.

this worked for me and i hope it works for you too.

Comment: I tried and I've got NOT_FOUND message when I tried to delete my deployments. What works for me was this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71507960/1184154

Comment: Apparently there was an outage in github actions yesterday, that could have been the problem....