# Github pages fails to deploy

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

This error is popping-up intermittently while trying to deploy my github webpages. I have no clue what to do, I already deleted and recreated the repository but the error persists. I have the same problem for all my github pages repositories.

Here is one repository example: https://github.com/cnftstats/borgs

```
Run actions/deploy-pages@v1
Actor: github-pages[bot]
Action ID: 1998855719
Artifact URL: https://pipelines.actions.githubusercontent.com/odmqpuZ7yGar25NNWIM53v9pBjO9vEwDjecGIYtf9ECZfcxi8V/_apis/pipelines/workflows/1998855719/artifacts?api-version=6.0-preview
{"count":1,"value":[{"containerId":359584,"size":14684160,"signedContent":null,"fileContainerResourceUrl":"https://pipelines.actions.githubusercontent.com/odmqpuZ7yGar25NNWIM53v9pBjO9vEwDjecGIYtf9ECZfcxi8V/_apis/resources/Containers/359584","type":"actions_storage","name":"github-pages","url":"https://pipelines.actions.githubusercontent.com/odmqpuZ7yGar25NNWIM53v9pBjO9vEwDjecGIYtf9ECZfcxi8V/_apis/pipelines/1/runs/21/artifacts?artifactName=github-pages","expiresOn":"2022-06-15T13:26:01.9505756Z","items":null}]}
Creating deployment with payload:
{
    "artifact_url": "https://pipelines.actions.githubusercontent.com/odmqpuZ7yGar25NNWIM53v9pBjO9vEwDjecGIYtf9ECZfcxi8V/_apis/pipelines/1/runs/21/artifacts?artifactName=github-pages&%24expand=SignedContent",
    "pages_build_version": "bf8f96d22c5dd116a5d94ee24cd398bdda60035f",
    "oidc_token": "***"
}
Failed to create deployment for bf8f96d22c5dd116a5d94ee24cd398bdda60035f.
{"message":"Deployment request failed for bf8f96d22c5dd116a5d94ee24cd398bdda60035f due to in progress deployment. Please cancel e92de3f483b775a12d4f784d7cc661ff2847fa62 first or wait for it to complete.","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-github-pages-deployment"}
Error: Error: Request failed with status code 400
Error: Error: Request failed with status code 400
Sending telemetry for run id 1998855719
```

Comment: Someone filed an issue: https://github.com/actions/deploy-pages/issues/22

Answer (score 14, accepted):

GitHub Actions is currently experiencing degraded performance and published this on their [status page](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/sksd097hm0y5). Therefore, you are most likely experiencing a side effect of the current problems. Other users are reporting the same [issue](https://github.com/actions/deploy-pages/issues/22) as well. Try again later when the issue has been resolved by GitHub.

Update: More products are now affected and experience degraded performance. Check their status page for more details: https://www.githubstatus.com

Comment: This isn't only a problem with Github Actions. I can't even create a new repository _or_ change my user settings anymore!

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Added an update to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If someone has an error **500** make sure you enabled the Build and deployment Source from "GitHub Actions".

Settings -> Pages section -> Build and deployment -> Source: GitHub Actions

Answer (score 1):

[It was a bug of GitHub, happens to all its users---date: 18/03/2022]

It happens to me today too.. :(

Maybe is a bug of GitHub pages: https://github.com/actions/deploy-pages/issues/22

https://github.community/t/pages-deploy-wedged-incorrect-request-failed-due-to-in-progress-deployment/234793/4

Comment: Make sure you delete previous failing actions and just re-run the latest one. It should work now.